# Heroku + Rails: weird error (Cedar Stack)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

So I have deployed my app to heroku for testing for a couple of weeks and since yesterday I keep getting the following kind of errors in the heroku logs:

```
Started GET "/user/shipping_address" for xx.xxx.xxx at 2012-02-09 15:46:37 +0000    
NameError (undefined local variable or method `sign_up_path' for #<UsersController:0x000000036210a8>):
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:57:in `require_user'
```

Another one:

```
Started POST "/purchase/search" for xx.xxx.xxx at 2012-02-09 15:31:30 +0000
NameError (undefined local variable or method `sign_up_path' for #<PurchasesController:0x000000051a3d08>):
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:57:in `require_user'
```

I also keep getting (really) weird javascript errors in firebug, like "object_id" missing, where object_id should never be used at that point in code.

It works without any flaws in the local environment on development/production and also all the time before on my heroku app.

Any hints greatly appreciated. This error is really killing me.
Best, Phil

(Cedar-Stack, Rails 3.0, authlogic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I updated authlogic to the newest version 3.1.0 (think it was on 3.0.3) and everything works for now.